# Function pointer decleration in Wikipedia article

Tags: c, function-pointers, typedef, function-declaration

In wikipedia's article about typedef is the following example on the use of typedef for function pointers:

```c
typedef void (*sighandler_t)(int);

sighandler_t signal(int sig, sighandler_t func);
```

Maybe since I am a novice in C, this confuses me: sighandler_t is a pointer to a function with 1 int parameter, how can signal be declared with an int + another function pointer in the next line?
Any help is appreciated!

The article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typedef

Comment: `signal` accepts a `sighandler_t` argument and returns one too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to think about this and build it up in stages.  It can be confusing even with the typedef.  (Without the typedef it's even *more* confusing!)

Yes, a signal handler is a function taking one `int` and returning `void`, like this:

```
void handler(int);
```

To create a pointer to a function like that, we add a `*` (to indicate a pointer) and a pair of parentheses to keep the precedence straight:

```
void (*funcptr)(int);
```

To "name" that type -- that is, to describe it succinctly but abstractly as a type name, but without mentioning an identifier -- we literally just drop the identifier:

```
void (*)(int)
```

What does that mean?  Well, if I write `int` you know I'm talking about C's plain integer type.  If I write `int *` you know I'm talking about a pointer to an `int`.  And if I write `void (*)(int)` you know (once you've understood the rather baffling-looking nomenclature) that I'm talking about a pointer to a function that takes an `int` and returns `void`.

So if we want, we can make a typedef out of that:

```
typedef void (*sighandler_t)(int);
```

Here I've added an identifier (`sighandler_t`) back in, and added the keyword `typedef` out in front.  What `typedef` means is that `sighandler_t` is not going to be a pointer to a function taking `int` and returning `void` like in a regular variable declaration -- rather, it is an *alias* or *synonym* for the type name "pointer to a function taking `int` and returning `void`".  (One way to think about `typedef` is that it's like `#define`, but on steroids.)

So now whenever we say `sighandler_t`, it's just like saying `void (*)(int)`, or "pointer to function taking `int` and returning `void`".

Now, `signal` is a function that accepts (a) a signal number and (b) a pointer to a new handler function for that signal.  So it's

```
signal(int sig, sighandler_t func)
```

That is, `func` is going to be a pointer to a signal-handling function, a function accepting one `int` and returning `void`.

But `signal` also *returns* the previous signal handler, the one replaced by the new `func` passed in.  So in full it's

```
sighandler_t signal(int sig, sighandler_t func)
```

Hopefully that makes sense.  It makes sense because the typedef performs a vital notational simplification for us.

Without the typedef, we'd have something like

```
void (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(int)
```

which is just about perfectly unreadable.  I'm not going to try to come up with a way of explaining that on its face.  (I'm also not going to describe the error-prone process I used to take the simpler, typedef-using form and mechanically derive this jawbreaker, without really understanding it.)

Comment: Thank you for this amazing answer! I think what has confused me most was the notation of the signal function without typedef, I was thinking why is it wrong to notate it like `void (*)(int) signal(int sig, void (*)(int))(int)`. Maybe can you correct my wrong thinking about why is this notation wrong?

Comment: @Student Well, as I said, the non-typedeffed declarations are just about impossible to understand.  One problem I can see is with what you wrote in your comment is that you don't have a `*` next to the identifier `signal`, so whatever this is, it's not the declaration of a function that returns a pointer.  (I can also tell you that when I tried to write the non-typedeffed declaration in my answer, I got it totally wrong at first, too.)

Comment: I meant something like `void (*)(int) (*signal)(int sig, void (*)(int))(int)` would be more readable where the positions correspond to the familiar function prototype `return_type func_name(param_1, param_2, ...)`

Comment: @Student I can still be completely clueless as to which set of parentheses to put which arguments in!  There's a program called `cdecl` that can help.  (I think there's a web version, too.)

Comment: Even https://cdecl.org/ gives for `void (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(int)` a Syntax Error :-)

Answer (score 3):

The function `signal` has its own type

```
sighandler_t (int sig, sighandler_t func)
```

or written as a function pointer then

```
sighandler_t ( * )(int sig, sighandler_t func)
```

It is its return type and the second parameter type are of the function pointer type `sighandler_t`.

That is the function `signal` returns pointer to a function of the type `sighandler_t` and has two parameters: the first one of the type `int` and the second one of the type `sighandler_t`.

Without the typedef

```
typedef void (*sighandler_t)(int);
```

the declaration of the function `signal` will look like

```
void ( * signal(int sig, void ( *func )( int ) )( int );
```

For the function `signal` you could introduce a typedef for its type the following way

```
typedef sighandler_t ( signal_t )( int, sighandler_t );
```

and then declare (but not define) the function `signal` like

```
signal_t signal;
```

Here is a demonstrative program that I hope will help to understand function declarations of functions that return function pointers or/and have parameters of function pointer types.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f( int x )
{
    printf( "%d ", x );
}

typedef void ( *FP )( int );

FP g( const int a[], size_t n, FP fp )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        fp( a[i] );
    }
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    return fp;
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 5 };
    
    int a[N] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int b[N] = { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
    
    FP fp = g( a, N, f );
    
    g( b, N, fp );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 3 4 5 
5 4 3 2 1
```

Comment: Is typedef declaring a new type of pointer called sighandler_t, which points to a function that takes 1 int argument and returns nothing?

Comment: @Student The typedef introduces an alias for the function pointer type void ( * )( int ).

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the second line declares `signal` as a function that receives a pointer to a function of type `sig_handler_t` as one of its input parameters and returns a pointer to a function of type `sig_handler_t`.  The function `signal` itself is not of type `sig_handler_t`.

In the Wikipedia sample, the two lines in the question are used to simplify:

`void (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(int);`

Here `void (*func)(int)` specifies a parameter `func` that is of equivalent type to `sig_handler_t`.  Additionally, wrapping the declaration with `void (* ... )(int)` would specify a return value of type `sig_handler_t`, although I have never seen anyone do something like this in practice.